# How to retrieve objects from an array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, object

I have an array with multiple objects, where each object has the following items in it: `tenantName`, `tenantAddress`, `tenantID`.

I need to display only the `tenantName` in the list view.  How can I retrieve just the name from this array?

This is my code

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a class name Info set up Getter and setter for the variables

```
public class Info {

private String tenantName;
private String tenantAddress;
private inttenantId;

public Info(){
    tenantName="Default_Name";
    tenantAddress="DefaultAdress";
    inttenantId=0;
}

//Getter and setter to set and get data 
public String getTenantAddress() {
    return tenantAddress;
}

public void setTenantAddress(String tenantAddress) {
    this.tenantAddress = tenantAddress;
}

public String getTenantName() {
    return tenantName;
}

public void setTenantName(String tenantName) {
    this.tenantName = tenantName;
}

public int getTenantId() {
    return tenantId;
}

public void setTenantId(int tenantId) {
    this.tenantId = tenantId;
}
}
```

And in your main activity

```
Info[] data=new Info[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    data[i]=new Info();
    //Initialize your variable
}
ArrayList<String> ARRAY=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   ARRAY.add(data.getTenantName());
}
code adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, ARRAY);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks.I got that working.I have a adapter which hold this data.I can populate the list view from this adapter with the tenant name however i am not sure how to perform search by character on the tenantName using my adapter.I can perform search by using the ARRAY but binding the tenant id seems trouble again with the selected row so i can display the details on of the selected row in next view.

Comment: You have to setup onClickListener(Something equivalent to that) in your ListView(or RecyclerView) and get the position of the item selected in the listview, store this value in a variable position, and Info dataSend=data[position] is the value that you need to send to your view, let me know if you have a confusion